# PHPUnit: Is there something like "assertExistsNotNull"?

Tags: php, testing, phpunit, assert

I recently detected the following problem:

```
self::assertNull($someArray[$someIndex]);
```

If *$someIndex* is not an existing index of *$someArray*, *$someArray[$someIndex]* will evaluate to *null* and *assertNull(null)* will say everything is okay. So basically PHPUnit is hiding a problem.

Is there something like

```
self::assertExistsNotNull($someArray[$someIndex]);
```

which only is true if *$someArray[$someIndex]* exists and is not *null*?

Answer (score 2):

You can use `assertArrayHasKey()` in addition to `assertNull()` as explained in [the documentation](https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/appendixes.assertions.html)

Comment: Thanks, but I'd rather have only one method (call).

Comment: What is the reason for only having a single method call? Multiple assertions is not a bad thing.

Comment: You can write your own assertion methods in an abstract/base class.

Comment: @Matthew Usurp What is the reason for *[]* over *array()*? What is the reason for *??* ?

Answer (score 0):

It seems like your problem is not that PHPUnit is "hiding" problems but that you are hiding problems with your PHP error reporting settings.

PHP will throw a notice for an undefined index.   I'd highly recommend you both develop and test with error_reporting set to E_ALL and display_errors enabled.  Therefore, during testing, you will see a problem if it is undefined and therefore, you don't need to add a  new assertion.

Comment: Actually you are (almost) right. *error_reporting* is set to *E_ALL* and *display_errors* is set to 1 but there is a "smart" framework catching all kind of errors (including notices) and "handling" them by hiding notices.

Comment: A "smart" framework that hides notices in a non-production environment?  Doesn't seem so smart to me.

Comment: You can set up your own error handler using set_error_handler, just set one up to throw an exception in your phpunit bootstrap file.

Comment: `E_ALL` is not (good) enough. During development you want `error_reporting=-1`.

Comment: @SebastianBergmann, E_ALL includes everything... hence the name

Answer (score 0):

You could write your own assertion : https://phpunit.de/manual/6.5/en/extending-phpunit.html#extending-phpunit.custom-assertions

Or write something like that :

```
self::assertThat($someArray, self::logicalAnd(self::arrayHasKey($someIndex), self::logicalNot(self::isNull())));
```